# Making an 'optional' parser using optparse-applicative and constructing value for recursive data type

Tags: haskell, optparse-applicative

I have a data type called `EntrySearchableInfo` written like this

```
type EntryDate = UTCTime -- From Data.Time

type EntryTag = Tag -- String

type EntryName = Name -- String

type EntryDescription = Description -- String

type EntryId = Int
```

```
data EntrySearchableInfo
  = SearchableEntryDate EntryDate
  | SearchableEntryTag EntryTag
  | SearchableEntryName EntryName
  | SearchableEntryDescription EntryDescription
  | SearchableEntryId EntryId
```

Basically represents things that make sense in 'search' context.

I want to write a function with this type

```
entrySearchableInfoParser :: Parser (Either String EntrySearchableInfo)
```

which (I think) will be a combination of several primitive `Parser <Type>` functions I have already written

```
entryDateParser :: Parser (Either String UTCTime)
entryDateParser = parseStringToUTCTime <$> strOption
  (long "date" <> short 'd' <> metavar "DATE" <> help entryDateParserHelp)

searchableEntryDateParser :: Parser (Either String EntrySearchableInfo)
searchableEntryDateParser = SearchableEntryDate <$$> entryDateParser -- <$$> is just (fmap . fmap)

searchableEntryTagParser :: Parser (Either String EntrySearchableInfo)
searchableEntryTagParser = ...
...
```

So I have two questions:

1. How do I combine those parsers to make `entrySearchableInfoParser` functions.
2. `EntrySearchableInfo` type is a part of a larger `Entry` type defined like this

```
data Entry
    = Add EntryDate EntryInfo EntryTag EntryNote EntryId
    | Replace EntrySearchableInfo Entry
    | ...
    ...
```

I already have a function with type

```
entryAdd :: Parser (Either String Entry)
```

which constructs `Entry` using `Add`.

But I'm not sure how to make `Entry` type using `Replace` with `entrySearchableInfoParser` and `entryAdd`.

Comment: You know that your `EntrySearchableInfo` type can only have 5 different values?

Comment: Yeah I do, idea is if the user inputs any 'searchable' thing, `entrySearchableInfoParser` should construct a `Parser (Either String EntrySearchableInfo)` type. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I mean it won't contain value of tag, only the fact it is tag.

Comment: @talex You're right! I completely missed that. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So combining those parsers were a lot simpler than I imagined.

I just had to use [<|>](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%3C%7C%3E)

```
entrySearchableInfoParser :: Parser (Either String EntrySearchableInfo)
entrySearchableInfoParser =
  searchableEntryDateParser
    <|> searchableEntryTagParser
    <|> searchableEntryNameParser
    <|> searchableEntryDescriptionParser
    <|> searchableEntryIdParser
```

and constructing `Entry` type using `Replace` with `entrySearchableInfoParser` and `entryAdd` was too.

```
entryAdd :: Parser (Either String Entry)
entryAdd = ...

entryReplace :: Parser (Either String Entry)
entryReplace = liftA2 Edit <$> entrySearchableInfoParser <*> entryAdd
```

Now it works perfectly!